# Get a unique row based on a column item in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql query to return IT tickets and their satisfaction scores however because of the way our ticketing system works this sometimes returns 2 rows for a ticket reference - 1 with a "Not Rated" rating and one with the real rating.

My question is, is there a way to get the query to only return a single row for each Ticket Reference and only return the "Not Rated" rating if another rating does not exist.  i.e. when there are 2 rows with the same ticket reference and one has a rating of "Excellent" and one has a rating of "Not Rated" that it only returns the row with the "Excellent" rating.  Any with only 1 row that is "Not Rated" should be returned.

The query looks like this so far -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.Rating_Date,
    t.id AS 'Ticket Reference',
    [Rating]
            = CASE
            When tt.[rating_id] = 20 then 'Poor'
            When tt.[rating_id] = 15 then 'Average'
            When tt.[rating_id] = 17 then 'Good'
            When tt.[rating_id] = 6 then 'Excellent'
            else 'Not Rated'
            END,
    [subject],
    [priority],
    [status],
    uu.name,
    [assignee_id],
    [Location],
    [technology]

FROM 
    [DB1].[dbo].[table1] t

    INNER JOIN  [DB1].[dbo].[table2] tt 
                ON t.id=tt.ticket_id

    LEFT JOIN   [DB1].[dbo].[table3] uu 
                ON t.assignee_id=uu.id

WHERE 
    t.rating_date > '2013-07-01'
    AND status = 'closed'
    AND location = 'UK'
    AND technology <> 'Not Known'
    AND group_id = '5678912'

ORDER BY 
    t-rating_date
```

Comment: What is the tt.[rating_id] for "Not Rated"?

Comment: Mark your comment, "query to only return a single row for each Ticket Reference and only return the "Not Rated" rating if another rating does not exist" but is that true in your table that multiple rows with other ratings(i.e. except not 'NotRated' rating)  exist for same ticket refrence.

Comment: I think that there can be 2 rows MAX: one marked as *Not rated* and, eventually, the second with the actual rate

Comment: @trippino no rating ID as in the other table it is just blank and I need it to be something other than blank hence the "Not Rated" entry.

Comment: @DeepakBhatia that is correct.  There are a maximum of 2 rows for each ticket - one "Not Rated" and one with the real rating.  Not all have 2 rows.

Comment: Ok so you should order by DESC if you use my solution

Comment: You can select `TOP(1)` and use `Order By rating_id DESC` .

Comment: if some answer fit you need please mark the question as resolved, otherwise please leave a comment or a question edit

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap the first query, order it by `rating_id` (if *Not rated* value is 0 you should order `DESC`, if *Not rated* is the highest you should order `ASC`) and then select the first record using the [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) function of sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the following logic can be implemented here. Please, be aware of that I am using sample data and in order to implement the solution you should understand the idea.

Let's say we have the following data:

[image]

Note: I am using id "0" for "Not Rated" status.

If I have understand your need correctly, the output data should be something like this:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above, for Tickets with IDs 1 and 4 we have "Not Rated" records, but we are not showing them. The "Not Rated" state is displayed only for Ticket with ID 3.

The solution:

```
;WITH DataSource  AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TicketID] ORDER BY [TicketRateID] DESC) AS [RowNumber]
          ,[TicketID]
          ,[TicketRateID]
    FROM @DataSource

)
SELECT [TicketID]
      ,[RowNumber]
      ,[TicketRateID]
FROM DataSource
```

The SQL statement above is using [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function in order to create a unique ID for each set of records for given tickets. We are sorting the records with DESC directive in order to be sure the "0"/"Not rated" records will have bigger ID.

The output of previous statement is:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot above, we need to display only this records with RowNumber equal to 1. This is done simple with WHERE clause.

Follows, full working example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
    (
         [TicketID] TINYINT
        ,[TicketRateID] TINYINT
    )

    INSERT INTO @DataSource ([TicketID],[TicketRateID])
    VALUES (1,6)
          ,(1,0)
          ,(2,20)
          ,(3,0)
          ,(4,0)
          ,(4,15)


    ;WITH DataSource  AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TicketID] ORDER BY [TicketRateID] DESC) AS [RowNumber]
              ,[TicketID]
              ,[TicketRateID]
        FROM @DataSource

    )
    SELECT [TicketID]
          ,[RowNumber]
          ,[TicketRateID]
    FROM DataSource
    WHERE [RowNumber] = 1  

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```